# GitLab: Transferring project to Group shows 403 Forbidden error

Tags: gitlab, project, transfer

> $ curl -k -X --request POST -H "Private-Token:Gybr7vzbGHuKDv9PM62z" https://gitlab_host/api/v3/groups/2257/projects/2884
>
> {"message":"403 Forbidden"}

I get the above error. The private token I am using is of my userid and I own both the group (groupid=2257) and the project(projectid=2884).
I can also transfer the project from the GUI. The above problem is only with the API. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here - to create the project by specifying the namespace_id (groupid). It seems to be adding into the group.

> curl -k -X POST -H "Private-Token: XXXXXXXXXXX" "https://gitlab_host/api/v3/projects?name=Team9&namespace_id=2257"

where 2257 is the groupid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like only the gitlab administrator is allowed to move a project to a group using the API (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/groups.html#transfer-project-to-group)).

> Transfer a project to the Group namespace. **Available only for admin**

Comment: I saw that but was wondering how it is working with GUI. But indeed, it meant only for the API.

Answer (score 0):

See [GitLab 15.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/09/22/gitlab-15-4-released/#api-endpoint-to-get-group-transfer-locations) (September 2022) can help with:

> ### API endpoint to get group transfer locations
>
> We added a new Groups API endpoint that returns a list of groups to which you can transfer the current group.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#get-groups-to-which-a-user-can-transfer-a-group) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/371117).

That way, you can list first the groups to which you can transfer the current group of your current project.
Meaning you will transfer your project to a group you know you can transfer to (no 403)